# reading and copying files from a card reader via python

Tags: python, storage

I've not used python a lot, but I was wanting to create a continuous script that runs in the background and looks for a new drive being plugged in. I was wanting the script to be able to take all the files from the drive and stores them in another place that I specify. Is this something that someone could help me with or should I look elsewhere? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
import subprocess
import time

def get_drives():
    """Return a list of disk drives"""
    output = subprocess.check_output("fsutil fsinfo drives")
    return output[output.find(b":")+1:].decode("utf-8").split()

sleep_interval = 60 # seconds

while True:
    # get a list of the current drives
    drives = get_drives()
    try:
        time.sleep(sleep_interval)
        # check for new drives
        new_drives = get_drives()
        for drive in new_drives:
            if drive not in drives:
                print(drive, "detected")
                # do more stuff here
        # update stored drives so we can detect removal & reinsertion
        drives = new_drives
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting")
        break
```

For your testing you'll probably want to set the sleep interval to a second or so.
Press `Ctrl+C` to exit.

Example run:

```
J:\>python drive_check.py
D:\ detected
Exiting
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks a million!